# Why seaborn histogram plot with kernel density estimator fails to change the color?

Tags: python, seaborn, histogram

I was trying to plot a histogram with kernel density estimator using seaborn. First I used `seaborn.distplot`, but I got a warning that '`distplot` is a deprecated function and will be removed in a future version.'

So I used `seaborn.histplot`, but when I used the same argument `kde_kws=dict(linewidth = 2 , color = 'black')`, I got an error 'unexpected keyword argument 'linewidth' and 'color'.

But I checked the documents showing that the argument in the two functions is seems used in the same way that the argument is passed to `seaborn.kdeplot()`. And this function `seaborn.kdeplot()` indeed has the argument 'color'. So my question is why it works on `distplot`, but fails to work on `histplot`?

```
sb.distplot(sn2, bins = 10, kde = True, color = 'teal', kde_kws=dict(linewidth = 2 , color = 'black'))
```

[image]

```
sb.histplot(sn2, bins = 10, kde = True, color = 'teal', kde_kws = dict(linewidth = 2, color = 'red'))
```

[image]

Meanwhile, when I used argument `line_kws = dist(linewidth = 2, color = 'red')`, I got no error. And it succeeded in changing the linewidth but failed to change the color.

```
sb.histplot(sn2, bins = 10, kde = True, color = 'teal', line_kws = dict(linewidth = 2, color = 'red'))
```

[image]

Can anyone explain to me why this happened? Thank you in advance.

Comment: [kde] as a tag refers to the desktop environment, doesn't refer to kernel density estimation.